Insert rows when the duplicate is missing
I have a dataframe of duplicates, but some are missing:
df <- data.frame(Var = c(rep("A",2), "B", rep("C",2), rep("D",2), "E"),
                 Count = c(12, 7, 9, 4, 10, 21, 8, 13))

View(df)

Var   Count
A     12
A     7
B     9
C     4
C     10
D     21
D     8
E     13

For every observation in Var that's missing its duplicate (e.g. B and E), I would like to add a row accordingly:
Var   Count
A     12
A     7
B     9
B     0
C     4
C     10
D     21
D     8
E     13
E     0

I 've seen other people using functions such as expand, expand.grid, and complete, but trying to implement these didn't get me anywhere. So what to do here?

Maybe you can use reframe + replace_na
df %>%
  reframe(Count = replace_na(Count[1:2], 0), .by = Var)

which gives
   Var Count
1    A    12
2    A     7
3    B     9
4    B     0
5    C     4
6    C    10
7    D    21
8    D     8
9    E    13
10   E     0


Using dplyr:
df |> 
  mutate(id = row_number(), .by = Var) |>
  right_join(expand.grid(id = seq_len(2), Var = unique(df$Var))) |>
  mutate(Count = coalesce(Count,  0), id = NULL)

#    Var Count
# 1    A    12
# 2    A     7
# 3    B     9
# 4    B     0
# 5    C     4
# 6    C    10
# 7    D    21
# 8    D     8
# 9    E    13
# 10   E     0


An approach using unnest
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(c_new = if_else(n() == 1, list(c(Count, 0)), list(NA)), .by = Var) %>%
  unnest(c_new) %>% 
  mutate(Count = coalesce(c_new, Count), c_new = NULL)
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   Var   Count
   <chr> <dbl>
 1 A        12
 2 A         7
 3 B         9
 4 B         0
 5 C         4
 6 C        10
 7 D        21
 8 D         8
 9 E        13
10 E         0


You can do the following:
data.table::setDT(df)[, .(Count =  if(.N<2) c(Count,0) else Count), Var]

Output:
       Var Count
    <char> <num>
 1:      A    12
 2:      A     7
 3:      B     9
 4:      B     0
 5:      C     4
 6:      C    10
 7:      D    21
 8:      D     8
 9:      E    13
10:      E     0

The dplyr equivalent is here:
reframe(df, Count=if(n()<2) c(Count,0) else Count,.by = Var)


Base R
> by(df, ~Var, \(x) {
+   if (nrow(x) == 1) merge(x, data.frame(Var=x$Var, Count=0), all=TRUE, sort=FALSE) else x
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
    Var Count
A.1   A    12
A.2   A     7
B.1   B     9
B.2   B     0
C.4   C     4
C.5   C    10
D.6   D    21
D.7   D     8
E.1   E    13
E.2   E     0

